# Server Load & Scalability for Massive Uploads

Tags: file-upload, scalability

I want to upload millions of audio items by users to my server. The current app has designed to give the contents, transcode them and finally send by ftp to storage servers. I want to know:

1. Does the app server can bear the enormous tasks by user like commenting, uploading, transcoding after scaling to more servers (to carry web app load)?
2. If the answer of above question is yes, is it correct and best approach? Because a good architecture will be to send transcoding to storage servers wait for finishing the job and sending respond to app server but at the same time it has more complexity and insecurity.
3. What is the common method for this type of websites?
4. If I send the upload and transcoding job to storage servers does it compatible with enterprise storage technologies in a long term scalability?

5- The current App is based on PHP. Is it possible to move tmp folder to another servers to overcome upload overload?

Thanks for answer, for tmp folder question number 5. I mean the tmp folder in Apache. I know that all uploaded files before moving to final storage destination (eg: storage servers or any solution) are stored in tmp folder of apache. I was wondering if this is a rule for apache and all uploaded files should be located first in app server, so how can I control, scale and redirect this massive load of storage to a temporary storage or server? I mean a server or storage solution as tmp folder of appche to just be guest of uploaded files before sending to the final storages places. I have studied and designed all the things about scaling of database, storages, load balancing, memcache etc. but this is one of my unsolved question. Where new arrived files by users to main server will be taken place in a scaled architect? And what is the common solution for this? (In one box solution all files will be temporary in the tmp dir of appche but for massive amount of contents and in a scaled system?). 
Regards

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at the Viddler architecture: http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/5/10/viddler-architecture-7-million-embeds-a-day-and-1500-reqsec.html

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't feel I can answer this (I wanted to add a comment, but my text was too long), some thoughts:

1. If you are creating such a large system (as it sounds) you should have some performance tests to see, how many concurrent connections/uploads,... whatever your architecture can handle. As I always say: If you don't know it: "no, it can't ".
2. I think the best way to deal with heavy load (this is: a lot of uploads, requiring a lot of blocked Threads from the appserver (-> this means, I would not use the Appserver to handle the fileuploads). Perform all your heavy operations (transcoding) asynchronously (e.g. queue the uploaded files, processess them afterwards). In any case the Applicaiton server should not wait for the response of the transcoding system -> just tell the user, that his file are going to be processed and send him a message (or whatever) when its finished. You can use something like gearman for that.
3. I would search for existing architectures, that have to handle a lot of uploads/conversion too (e.g. flickr) just go to slideshare and search for "flickr" or "scalable web architecture"
4. I do not really understand this - but I would use Servers based on their tasks (e.g. Applicaiton server, Database serversm, Transconding servers, Storage,...) - each server should do, what he can do best.
5. I am afraid I don't know what you are talking about when you say tmp folder.

Good luck

Comment: I agree with Bernhard's answer. You can't expect to handle millions of users (concurrently or not) while transcoding files synchronously. Let the users upload files and then do hard work in the background, or send it off to other servers. You also have to realize that enterprise storage solutions are only as scalable as the size of your wallet.

Comment: To be honest I don't think I can answer your question directly or give you tips how to configure Apache, your filesystem etc., but  I would seperate all systems, so that an outage of a subsystem does not bring down your complete service. There may be servers that are more suitable for a lot of uploads thatn Apache, maybe you can get some tips from other users that have more expirience with different webservers (lighttp seems to be good, but I do not have any numbers). Again I recommend to search for existing   projects that have similar problems (e.g. a lot of uploads).